# Merge [python-pil] into [pil]?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

The [python-pil](/questions/tagged/python-pil) tag has two questions, and is redundant because of the used [pil](/questions/tagged/pil) tag. It would be nice to merge them.

Comment: Ok, it's all done now, `pil` and `python-pil` have been merged into `python-imaging-library`.  We prefer the descriptive names, so we took the long form of the library name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With only 2 questions, it's easy enough to re-tag those questions. I've done so now.

I've proposed `python-pil` as a synonym for [pil](/questions/tagged/pil) (I meet the requirements for synonym suggestions). Once it reaches a +4 vote tally (anyone with 5 points or more on the tag can vote) it'll be made a synonym.

Comment: Let's go with `python-imaging-library` and set the other two as synonyms of that.  We like descriptive tag names.  My first thought at seeing `pil` is WTF?

Comment: @casperOne: +1 on that, it had crossed my mind as well to propose that as the better name. You are in an excellent position to make that one happen. :-)

Comment: Oh, FFS, there's already a `python-imaging-library` and it's mapped to `pil`.  Give me a few while I sort out this mess.

Comment: @casperOne: :-D I thought that that's how you found the long form in the first place!

Comment: Ok, it's all done now, `pil` and `python-pil` have been merged into `python-imaging-library`.

Comment: @casperOne: Any chance you can recover the tag wiki at all? I cannot for the life of me remember what it read now.

Comment: @casperOne: Ah, google has the excerpt at least, will restore that.

Comment: Sorry, `python-imaging-library` *had* the other one (I believe).  If you point me to the copy, I'll fix it.

Comment: @casperOne: I restored the wiki from the Google cache, I found the full wiki page as well. I have the rep to do so at least. :-)

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated.